# bash printf duplicate line

Tags: bash, printf

I expect to print

```
$ pwd: /home/me/actual_folder size: 5.3M
```

with:

```
$ cat test.sh
printf 'pwd: %s size:%s\n' `pwd` `du -sh .`
$
```

But I get:

```
$ sh test.sh
pwd: /tmp/actual_folder size:5.3M
pwd: . size:
$
```

How to avoid the last `pwd: . size:` line ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the dot from the output of `du`:

```
printf 'pwd: %s size: %s\n' `pwd` `du -sh . | cut -f1`
```

Otherwise, the second command substitution outputs two words, so printf sees 3 arguments, so it repeats the template for the second pair (dot and nothing).

You can also use pwd as the argument of du directly, but you need to revert the order of the output:

```
printf 'pwd: %s size: %s\n' $(du -sh $(pwd) | awk '{print $2, $1}')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
printf "pwd: %s size:%s\n" "$(pwd)" "$(du -sh)"
```

But if you don't want the "." in the end you can cut it with:

```
 printf "pwd: %s size:%s\n" "$(pwd)" "$(du -sh | cut -d '.' -f1)"
```